# Using multiple vectors and trying to push_back

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a rabbit breeding program in c++.  I keep getting an error under the period in this line...

```
RabbitsM.push_back(Rabbit());
```

I need to be able to put in whether the rabbits are female or male and what color they are.  So what I was thinking is that I make two vectors (male and female) and I would like to have 4 slots in the vectors to have the color of the offspring (brown, white, black and spotted). The error I keep getting is...

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active) no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=float, _Alloc=std::allocator<float>]" matches the argument list
```

Here is my source code...

```
  class Rabbit {


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {

        int rabbits = 5;
        vector<float> RabbitsM;
        vector<float> RabbitsF;

        int sex = rand() % 2 + 1;
        if (sex == 1)
        {
            int color = rand() % 5;
            if (color == 1)//brown
            {
                RabbitsM.push_back(Rabbit());
            }
            else if (color == 2)//black
            {
                RabbitsM.push_back(Rabbit());

            }
            else if (color == 3)//white
            {
                RabbitsM.push_back(Rabbit());

            }
            else if (color == 4)//spotted
            {
                RabbitsM.push_back(Rabbit());

            }


        }
        else
        {
            int color = rand() % 5 + 1;
            int color = rand() % 5;
            if (color == 1)//brown
            {
                RabbitsF.push_back(Rabbit());
            }
            else if (color == 2)//black
            {
                RabbitsF.push_back(Rabbit());

            }
            else if (color == 3)//white
            {
                RabbitsF.push_back(Rabbit());

            }
            else if (color == 4)//spotted
            {
                RabbitsF.push_back(Rabbit());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
Can someone please help me!

Comment: Are you trying to put a rabbit in a vector of floats?

Comment: Please also add your declaration of `RabbitsM` and `Rabbit`

Comment: Here is what I have so far in my source code.  See above.

Comment: `int Rabbit::main()`???? I don't think `main` can be a member function. Why do you want to store rabbits as floats?

Comment: Rabbit is the name of the class.  I am going off of my instructors instructions and my book.  He has told us to use the line.  Should it be RabbitsM or RabbitsF instead of Rabbit?

Comment: You're trying to add a `Rabbit` to a collection of `float`s (`vector<float>`). A rabbit is not a float.

Comment: so it should be an int?  I am not sure how many will be in the vector because they are breeding so I thought a float would be better.

Comment: The type inside the brackets `vector<float>` is what is stored, not the size. If you want to store numbers, use `vector<int>`, floating point numbers, `vector<float>`, rabbits `vector<Rabbit>`, etc.

Comment: A `vector<float>` means it holds floats, a `vector<Rabbit>` means it holds `Rabbit`s.  Vectors always use a `std::size_t` for a size type.

Comment: I think the best answer for the OP is probably to [pull out a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start reading and writing small programs until they know enough of the terminology and methodology to understand the comments and answers.

Comment: @MicroVirus   I would like to be reconsidered on opening the question.  I have reworded the question.  I am a new student to C++ and am not sure how it works in its entirety.  I would like to thank those who did help.  I am starting to understand.  My instructor gave us a book that is online and it is not giving me much information.  so I come on here to try and find help.

Comment: Your edit changes your question substantially. You should ask a **new question** instead if you have further issues. That will also give you a fresh start (and a fresh set of eyes) to look at your question. I've rolled back the edit to preserve the original question.

Comment: As for the issue in your edit, you might want to check out the implementation of `set_values` in this [C++ Tutorial on classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) to see how your `setColor` should look, before posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, what you want to do is add the gender and the colour as a property (member variables) of the `Rabbit` class and store all rabbits in one collection `vector<Rabbit>`. As already mentioned in the other answer, this would also fix the issue with trying to put a `Rabbit` into a `float` collection.

Answer (score 0):

As @James Root has pointed out in the comments, you are attempting to add a `Rabbit` to a `std::vector<float>`. You need to change your `std::vector` to be a `std::vector<Rabbit>` and then you will be able to add `Rabbit` to them:

```
vector<Rabbit> RabbitsM;
vector<Rabbit> RabbitsF;
RabbitsM.push_back(Rabbit());
```

Comment: Thank you I added that and now it takes that error away but I am getting a new one...                                                                                     Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error LNK1561 entry point must be defined                                                                                                         And I have a main which is what it is telling my online when I look it up.

Comment: @TaraMallakJohnson You have main _inside_ of your Rabbit class.  Try putting it outside.

Comment: @ZirconiumHacker Thank you!

Comment: Okay that one is fixed and a new has shown up   LOL  I can't win.  Rabbbit() is where the code is.     RabbitsF.push_back(Rabbit());  This line is giving me 2 errors   (1)'main::Rabbit': no appropriate default constructor available
(2) incomplete type is not allowed

Comment: @TaraMallakJohnson You must have a default constructor for the `Rabbit` class.  Otherwise, you cannot put it into a vector.